# sencha touch Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isReady' of undefined sencha-touch-all.js:21

Tags: android, sencha-touch, touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm trying to run my app on my device or on an Android emulator, but I get the following error message :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isReady' of undefined sencha-touch-all.js:21
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sencha Touch Demo 2</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./touch2/resources/css-debug/sencha-touch.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./touch2/sencha-touch-all.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myapp.js"></script>
</head>
</html>
```

**myapp.js**

```
Ext.require([ 'Ext.MessageBox' ]);
Ext.require([ 'Ext.Label' ]);
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
enabled: true
});

Ext.application({

                name: 'touch-demo',


                controllers: [
                    'Main'
                ],

                models: [

                    'contato'

                ],

                stores: [

                    'contatos',

                    'remotecontatos'

                ],

                views: [

                    'contatoslist',

                    'ContatosForm',

                    'remoteListContato'
                ],


            viewport: {
                layout: {
                    type: 'card',
                    animation: {
                    type: 'slide',
                    duration: 1000
                        }
                    }
            },

            launch: function(){

            }
});
```

What can I do? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered running the app using a sencha packaged app?

I do all my testing on a browser first and then I build up a packaged build.

('Sencha app build package' on the command line)

The main difference between these two approaches is that you are not loading resources on the fly using Ext.Loader. As far as I understand it no mobile environment can use the loader so if you wanted to staticly refrence each of your app files in your index.html that should work too. I may be wrong there but there is some truth to that statement.

Plus better all-in-all to have your production app all minified and packaged up nicely.

Hope this helps.